# How x and y coordinates in vis-network smoothWorldCup example calculated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visnetwork, react-vis-network

I'm trying to render a service map. Some service(s) has many dependencies. I'm trying to group those service(s) with more number of connections in one area in the rendered layout. But I didn't found any solution for achieving the same.

I'm looking for something like the one shown in **[smoothWorldCup](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/edgeStyles/smoothWorldCup.html)** example. I could see the x and y coordinates are given in the dataset itself. So want to know how it is calculated or is there any algorithm which I can make use of to get the x and y coordinates based on canvas height, width and grouped nodes?